# How can I use Typescript with SapUI5 resolving the two module systems

Tags: typescript, sapui5

I am trying to use Typescript with SAPUI5, and I have seen several examples of creating a Typescript class, and then passing that to Controller.extend in the SAPUI5 controller.

The problem I'm having is when I try and use modules in Typescript such as "import * as $ from "jquery". Typescript generates the define() wrapper for the module, and injects 'require', 'export' and 'jquery'. When I try and load this, I get 'define not found' and when I include 'requirejs', I get 'export not found'.

This is the closest I've gotten, but it keeps the module systems separate, and needs a great deal of interface code:

index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>

<head>
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <title>Test App</title>

    <!--Loads from sapui5.hana.ondemand.com-->
    <script src="/resources/sap/ui/thirdparty/require.js"></script>

    <script src="/resources/sap-ui-core.js"
            data-sap-ui-theme='sap_bluecrystal'
            data-sap-ui-libs='sap.m,sap.ui.commons,sap.ui.table'
            data-sap-ui-bindingSyntax='complex'
            data-sap-ui-resourceroots='{"TestApp": "/testApp"}'>
    </script>

    <script>
        require(["/testApp/controller/tsclasses/Home.js"], function (contHome) {
            window.tsclasses = {
                controller: {
                    Home: contHome.default
                }
            };

            sap.ui.getCore().attachInit(function () {
                sap.m.Shell({
                    title: "Test App",
                    showLogout: true,
                    appWidthLimited: false,
                    app: new sap.ui.core.ComponentContainer({
                        height: "100%",
                        name: "TestApp"
                    })
                }).placeAt("content");
            });
        });
    </script>

</head>
<body id="content" style="margin: 0" class="sapUiBody">
</body>
</html>
```

Component.js

```
sap.ui.define(["sap/ui/core/UIComponent"], function (UIComponent) {
    "use strict";
    return UIComponent.extend("TestApp", {

        metadata: {
            rootView: "TestApp.view.App",
            routing: {
                config: {
                    routerClass: "sap.m.routing.Router",
                    viewPath: "TestApp.view",
                    controlId: "rootControl",
                    controlAggregation: "pages",
                    viewType: "XML"
                },
                routes: [
                    {
                        name: "home",
                        // empty hash - normally the start page
                        pattern: "",
                        target: "home"
                    }],
                targets: {
                    "home": {
                        viewName: "Home",
                        viewLevel: 0
                    }
                }
            }
        },

        init: function () {
            UIComponent.prototype.init.apply(this, arguments);

            var AppComponent = this;

            AppComponent.getRouter().initialize();
        }

    });
}, /* bExport= */ true);
```

Home.controller.js

```
sap.ui.define(
    ["sap/ui/core/mvc/Controller"],
    function (Controller) {

        "use strict";

        return Controller.extend("TestApp.controller.Home", new tsclasses.controller.Home());
    }
);
```

Home.ts

```
import * as $ from "jquery";
declare var sap: any;

namespace tsclasses.controller {
    export class Home extends sap.ui.core.mvc.Controller {
        public onInit(): void {
            alert('here');
            var x = $(window).width();
        }
    }
}

export default tsclasses.controller.Home;
```

App.view.xml

```
<View xmlns="sap.m">
    <App id="rootControl">
    </App>
</View>
```

Home.view.xml

```
<View
    xmlns="sap.m"
    controllerName="TestApp.controller.Home">

  <Page class="sapUiContentPadding"
        title="App Test Home">
    <content>

      <Text text="text" />

    </content>
  </Page>
</View>
```

This solution is well worth it for me, because I really want to use type checking and intellisense, but again, I'd really like to somehow have my Typescript module loader and the SAPUI5 module loader share state etc so that it works properly.

Comment: It looks as though 'require' and 'exports' are special values in the AMD model system. It maybe that I should be configuring my VS2017 project to use a different module system perhaps. Does anybody know which one?

Answer (score 0):

I haven't been able to find a proper solution to my problem, but I have determined what I think is the tidiest solution which uses fewer files overall.

Since VS 2017 type checks against referenced typing automatically, you don't need to import the target module e.g. if you want to typecheck for jquery, you don't have to do import * as $ from 'jquery'. Not having to import modules means that you can transpile Typescript without any module loader or module type functionality. You also have to switch down to ES5 output, because the ES6 output still outputs a line using the 'exports' variable.

My test files now look as follows:

**index.html:**

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>

<head>
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <title>Test App</title>

    <script src="/resources/sap-ui-core.js"
            data-sap-ui-theme='sap_bluecrystal'
            data-sap-ui-libs='sap.m,sap.ui.commons,sap.ui.table'
            data-sap-ui-bindingSyntax='complex'
            data-sap-ui-resourceroots='{"TestApp": "/testApp"}'>
    </script>

    <script>
        sap.ui.getCore().attachInit(function () {
            sap.m.Shell({
                title: "Test App",
                showLogout: true,
                appWidthLimited: false,
                app: new sap.ui.core.ComponentContainer({
                    height: "100%",
                    name: "TestApp"
                })
            }).placeAt("content");
        });
    </script>

</head>
<body id="content" style="margin: 0" class="sapUiBody">
</body>
</html>
```

**Component.js**

```
sap.ui.define(["sap/ui/core/UIComponent"], function (UIComponent) {
    "use strict";
    return UIComponent.extend("TestApp", {

        metadata: {
            rootView: "TestApp.view.App",
            routing: {
                config: {
                    routerClass: "sap.m.routing.Router",
                    viewPath: "TestApp.view",
                    controlId: "rootControl",
                    controlAggregation: "pages",
                    viewType: "XML"
                },
                routes: [
                    {
                        name: "home",
                        // empty hash - normally the start page
                        pattern: "",
                        target: "home"
                    }],
                targets: {
                    "home": {
                        viewName: "Home",
                        viewLevel: 0
                    }
                }
            }
        },

        init: function () {
            UIComponent.prototype.init.apply(this, arguments);

            var AppComponent = this;

            AppComponent.getRouter().initialize();
        }

    });
}, /* bExport= */ true);
```

**Home.controller.js**

In SAPUI5's model, the type 'TestApp.controller.Home' is exported into the global scope, so redefining the type immediately after the define replaces it, this allows us to define TestApp.controller.Home with a class written in Typescript. Also, SAPUI5 can load bare Javascript files into global scope without them being modules, so we can load required classes here - these two tricks allow us to get everything nicely into a single controller file.

```
declare var sap: any;

sap.ui.define(
    ["sap/ui/core/mvc/Controller", "/TestApp/controller/tsclasses/DataClass"],
    function (Controller: any, jsDataClass: any) {

        "use strict";

        return Controller.extend("TestApp.controller.Home", {});
    }
);

namespace TestApp.controller {
    export class Home extends sap.ui.core.mvc.Controller {
        public onInit() {
            var data = new tsclasses.controller.DataClass();
            alert(data.message);
            alert('width = ' + $(window).width());
        }
    }
}
```

**Home.ts** - removed - no longer required

**App.view.xml**

```
<View xmlns="sap.m">
    <App id="rootControl">
    </App>
</View>
```

**Home.view.xml**

```
<View
    xmlns="sap.m"
    controllerName="TestApp.controller.Home">

  <Page class="sapUiContentPadding"
        title="App Test Home">
    <content>

      <Text text="text" />

    </content>
  </Page>
</View>
```